# Why does my google Picker function return "Uncaught Error Vb"

Tags: firefox, vuejs3, google-picker

I have a Problem with the Google Picker API. I try to open the google Picker with this particular function:

```js
createPicker() {
      console.log('Create Picker');
      if (this.pickerApiLoaded && this.oauthToken) {
        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
          .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
          .addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS)
          .setOAuthToken(this.oauthToken)
          .setDeveloperKey(this.developerKey)
          .setCallback(this.pickerCallback)
          .build();
        picker.setVisible(true);
      }
    }
```

The `pickerCallback` function is just a console log for now. Every other element like `oauthToken` and `developerKey` aren't empty and are valid.

I also added all the scopes i need for google Drive in my Oauth consent screen in the google cloud console.

I tried to run the code and the Popup comes up that i should log in. As soon as i Press sign in an Oauth Popup opens and then instantly closes and in the console i get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Vb
    N https://www.gstatic.com/_/picker/_/js/k=picker.opms.en_US.NGskBAHYysI.O/d=1/rs=AGshSGNvq07PH88kzMigF5r5iwWV9-ZCTA/m=opnc:803
    O https://www.gstatic.com/_/picker/_/js/k=picker.opms.en_US.NGskBAHYysI.O
...
```

I don't know what to do anymore i've tested so many things.

Thanks for your help.